# "scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found" but working when started with -Xbootclasspath/p:scala-library.jar

Tags: scala, executable-jar, scala-compiler

I'm trying to run a Scala application packed as JAR (including dependencies) but this fails until the Scala library is added by using the `-Xbootclasspath/p` option.

Failing invocation:

```
java -jar /path/to/target/scala-2.10/application-assembly-1.0.jar
```

After the application did some of its intended output, the console shows:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime
>   in compiler mirror not found.
>           at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:48)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getPackage(Mirrors.scala:172)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredPackage(Mirrors.scala:175)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:181)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage(Definitions.scala:181)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:182)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass(Definitions.scala:182)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1015)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr(Definitions.scala:1014)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1144)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses(Definitions.scala:1143)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1187)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1187)
>           at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1252)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.(Global.scala:1290)
>           at extract.ScalaExtractor$Compiler$2$.(ScalaExtractor.scala:24)

Working invocation:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/home/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.2/lib/scala-library.jar -jar /path/to/target/scala-2.10/application-assembly-1.0.jar
```

The strange thing about it is that the `application-assembly-1.0.jar` was built so that it includes all dependencies including the Scala library. When one extracts the JAR file it can be verified that the class files in the `scala.runtime` package have been included.

**Creation of the JAR file**

`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.9.1")` was added to `project/plugins.sbt` and the `assembly` target was invoked. A JAR file of about 25MB results.

Building the JAR with proguard shows the same runtime behavior as seen with assembly's JAR file.

**Application code that triggers the MissingRequirementError**

Some application code works fine and the previously described exception is triggered as soon as the `new Run` from the following fragment executes.

```
import scala.reflect.internal.util.BatchSourceFile
import scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile
import scala.reflect.io.Path.jfile2path
import scala.tools.nsc.Global
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
…
import scala.tools.nsc._
object Compiler extends Global(new Settings()) {
  new Run // This is line 24 from the stack trace!

  def parse(path: File) = {
    val code = AbstractFile.getFile(path)
    val bfs = new BatchSourceFile(code, code.toCharArray)
    val parser = new syntaxAnalyzer.UnitParser(new CompilationUnit(bfs))
    parser.smartParse()
  }
}
val ast = Compiler.parse(file)
```

Among others, `scala-library`, `scala-compiler` and `scala-reflect` are defined as dependencies in `build.sbt`.

**For the curios / background information**

The aim of the application is to aid in localization of Java and Scala programs. The task of the code fragment above is to get an AST from a Scala file in order to find method calls in there.

**The questions**

- Given the Scala library is included in the JAR file, why is necessary to call the JAR using `-Xbootclasspath/p:scala-library.jar`?
- Why do other parts of the application run just fine even though `scala.runtime` is reported as missing later?

Comment: this might be because you have not given any classpath to that compiler run to use. Instead of `Global(new Settings())`, try giving it a settings that has the same classpath as your program: `settings.classpath.value = System.getProperty("java.class.path")`.

Comment: or maybe `settings.usejavacp.value = true`, or something similar...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. It seems I've wrongly assumed the compiler settings would default to those of the invoking program.
Adding either `settings.usejavacp.value = true` or `settings processArgumentString "-usejavacp"` will result in a correctly configured compiler and thus a working program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easy way to configure the settings with familiar keystrokes:

```
  import scala.tools.nsc.Global
  import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val s = new Settings
    s processArgumentString "-usejavacp"
    val g = new Global(s)
    val r = new g.Run
  }
```

That works for your scenario.

Even easier:

```
java -Dscala.usejavacp=true -jar ./scall.jar
```

Bonus info, I happened to come across [the enabling commit message](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/ae8c065594aa605734b66c11693e5e584feaeddd):

> Went ahead and implemented classpaths as described in email to
>   scala-internals on the theory that at this point I must know what I'm
>   doing.
>
> ** PUBLIC SERVICE ANNOUNCEMENT **
>
> If your code of whatever kind stopped working with this commit (most
>   likely the error is something like "object scala not found") you can
>   get it working again with either of:
>
> passing -usejavacp on the command line
>
> set system property "scala.usejavacp" to "true"
>
> Either of these will alert scala that you want the java application
>   classpath to be utilized by scala as well.

Comment: To anyone who gets a similar error when configuring Scala in Intellij IDEA, add this to "Additional compiler options" in Project Structure -> Facets -> Scala -> Compiler Options: "-usejavacp" I successuflly used this to solve fatal error: object scala.beans.BeanInfo in compiler mirror not found.

Comment: @Malcolm, I get to facets but then I cannot find Scala. I see no facets are configured. Press "+" to add a new facet. When I click +, Scala is not one of the options

Comment: Hmmm... do you have the Intellij IDEA Scala plugin? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala