# Why am I getting "object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found." with scala-maven-plugin when dependency is upgraded?

Tags: scala, scala-maven-plugin

I have a Maven based project that uses Scala. I tried to upgrade an internal dependency and now I get

```
[ERROR] : error while loading Object, Missing dependency 'class scala.native in compiler mirror', required by /modules/java.base/java/lang
/Object.class
[ERROR] ## Exception when compiling 59 sources to ...\target\classes
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
```

I am digging through the sub dependency differences but does anyone know why this might happen?

**Additional Information**

The error is super vague so I will update as best I can with more info.

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2958

Comment: Or maybe compiler option `-usejavacp` is missed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911848/object-scala-in-compiler-mirror-not-found-running-scala-compiler-programatical https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150961/scala-runtime-in-compiler-mirror-not-found-but-working-when-started-with-xboo